# How to create multiple lights in maya without naming error (python)

Tags: python, scripting, maya

I am currently working on creating a python script for a class assignment that would allow me to automatically generate multiple lights in different areas of a scene in Maya. Unfortunately, I've run into an issue. When I try to reuse the code for making a light or execute it consecutively, I keep running into this error with there already being a light named "aiLight1". Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Here's the code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import mtoa.utils as mutils


def create_light_rig(offset, light_rotation):
    myLight = mutils.createLocator("aiAreaLight", asLight = True)
    cmds.setAttr(myLight[0] + ".color", 1,0,0, type = "double")
    lighttransform_node = cmds.listRelatives(myLight, parent=True)
    key_light = lighttransform_node[0]

    cmds.move(0, 0, offset, key_light)
    cmds.move(0, 0, key_light + '.rotatePivot')
    cmds.rotate(-light_rotation, light_rotation, 0, key_light)

    rig_node = cmds.group(empty=True, name="LightRig")

    cmds.parent(key_light,rig_node)

create_light_rig(10, 30)
```

Attached is a screenshot of the issue I am talking about.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLOgI.jpg)

Comment: please post the code. Images are unhelpful...

Comment: Understood, just posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the first run, there is a light called `aiAreaLight1` in the scene. The probem is the listRelatives() which is not needed. The `createLocator()` function returns the shape node and the transform node, so you can simply use it as

```
key_light = myLight[1]
```

And everything should work.